# Unity - call Start in another script's class

Tags: unity

##### What I have:

1. A scene with only a cube (player), directional light and main camera.
2. A `Player` script containing functionality for movement and button press
3. A `Bullet` script that has two private members, GameObject and Material. They are loaded and set in the `Start()` function.

##### What I want:

I want to create a `Bullet` object (doing for example `Bullet bullet;`) when I press space. Inside the bullet `Start()` function the bullets mesh is created and position initialised. Thus the bullet should appear in the scene. It does not.

##### The issue:

There is no bullet that is created. Furthermore, I am unable to create a new bullet doing `Bullet bullet = new Bullet();` because `Bullet` is a class that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`.

##### Question:

How do I fix this? How do I execute another script's class's start function from my original script? I have tried to create an init class that is public and only calls Start of bullet but it does not work either!

Example of my bullet class:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {
private GameObject sphere;
private Material mat;

void Start() {
    this.transform.position = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    mat = Resources.Load("Materials/bullet", typeof(Material)) as Material;
    sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = mat;
  }
}
```

The above code is by no means complete and it may contain grammatical errors because the actual code is on another computer. I do not want feedback about how to transfer code from one computer to another nor do I want feedback on whether the example is the most efficient way to initialize the bullet object. If the initialization is wrong, however, for example, it should be in another function or perhaps be made with a special function, then I'd be more than happy to receive your guidance!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `Bullet bullet = new Bullet();` won't create a game object, I would recommend reading Unity's documentation about the Gameobject class

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you really want here is a factory method. Something like...

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {
     static Material _mat;

     public static Bullet Create() {
         var sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
         sphere.transform.position = Vector3.one;
         if (_mat == null) {
              mat = Resources.Load<Material>("Materials/bullet");
         }
         sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = mat;

         return sphere.AddComponent<Bullet>();
     }
}
```

Now your code can say `Bullet myBullet = Bullet.Create();` to instantiate a new bullet.

However, a much more conventional way to achieve this behaviour is to simply create a game object in a scene that has the mesh/material/script configurations you want, then drag it from the Hierarchy window into the Project window — placing it somewhere in or nested under your game's Assets folder. This creates what's called a "prefab". Other code can expose a serialized `Bullet bulletPrefab` field that you assign to point at that prefab. (Assuming the prefab has a `Bullet` component attached — change the type accordingly if you want to refer to a different component on the prefab, or `GameObject`/`Transform` if you don't care what components the prefab has)

Then you can spawn instances (copies) of that prefab with `Bullet myBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);` and Unity's deserializer handles creating and initializing the object according to the saved configuration, no special factory method needed.

---

The reason what you were trying originally didn't work is that `MonoBehaviour` scripts expect to be attached to `GameObject` instances. You can get this attachment if you spawn one from a prefab as described above, or attach one to an existing `GameObject` with `AddComponent`, or construct a new `GameObject` with a custom list of components like:

```
var go = new GameObject("newbie", typeof(MyComponent), typeof(MyOtherComponent);
```

But trying to use `Bullet myBullet` or `new Bullet()` will not on its own create a `GameObject`. The former creates a *slot* to store a `Bullet` (initially containing just `null`), and the latter just creates a free-floating `MonoBehaviour` instance, and throws a warning in your console reminding you that this is *not* the way to do it.

`MonoBehaviour` message functions are called only on `MonoBehaviour` scripts attached to `GameObject` instances in the scene. So no `GameObject` in the scene, no `Start()` call.

When you tried calling `Start()` manually, the first line it hit was:

```
this.transform.position = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

...which tries to access the `Transform` component attached to "this" `Bullet` instance's `GameObject`. But since it's not attached to any `GameObject`, this throws a null reference exception and aborts the method.